# How do I reduce drop-down size on Bootstrap menu?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown, nav

I have searched and searched and cannot figure out how to reduce my Bootstrap menu's drop-down size.  I have tried modifying everything related to drop-downs in the Bootstrap CSS and cannot get it change.

My  current Bootstrap dropdown:

[image]

I would like to make the space between each item smaller.  Here is my current custom nav CSS:

```
.navbar-brand,
.navbar-nav li a {
    line-height: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  Had to add this to my css code:

```
.navbar-brand,
.navbar-nav li a {
    line-height: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding-top: 0;
}

.dropdown-menu li a {
    line-height: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `line-height` and `height` property

```
.navbar-brand,
.navbar-nav li a {

    max-height: auto;
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

Update 1 :

```
.navbar-brand,
.navbar-nav > li> a {
    line-height: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

Use `>` to apply styles under the root class.

**[LIVE DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y248wVXxjr3DMXF4xlWy?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  but I am still trying to keep that height with my navbar.  Those height elements make it 100px tall,  i just dont want that to affect the dropdowns.

Comment: can you create a plunker demo?

Comment: @AKendrick did you see my demo?